# WP Admin Bar - Get current theme name as custom menu title

Tags: php, menus, multisite, admin-menu

I wish to echo the current theme in text in my WP Admin Bar sub menu.

How would I go about display a snippet of PHP inside the `'title' => 'php snippet here',` ?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_theme
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu

```
$theme_name = get_current_theme();
echo $theme_name;
```

Comment: You did not try this ?

 `$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'id' => 'node_id',
    'title' => get_current_theme()
) );`

Comment: I just tried it, and a few other thigs like wrapping that in ' plus adding , as well as copy / pasting and replacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing [`get_current_theme()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_theme) is deprecated since version 3.4 you need to use [`wp get theme()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_theme) to get the current theme name.

And about [add_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu) you can only use it at action hook `admin_bar_menu` as [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu) say about it:

> This is not a function. It is a method of the $wp_admin_bar global (an instance of WP_Admin_Bar), which may not exist except during the 'admin_bar_menu' hook.

Working example

```
function foo_test_menu() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $current_theme = wp_get_theme();
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'id' => 'your_menu_id',
        'title' => $current_theme->get('Name')
    ) );   
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'foo_test_menu');
```

Comment: very helpful! Thanks for the semantics. Once I reach 15 rep, I'll be back to vote up your answer...hooah!